# Prolog: geting false instead of a list

Tags: prolog

my knowlegde base is something like this

```
user (USERID, USERNAME,  [Tags])
```

for exameple

```
no(1,ana,[natureza,pintura,musica,sw,porto]).
no(11,antonio,[natureza,pintura,carros,futebol,lisboa]).
no(12,beatriz,[natureza,musica,carros,porto,moda]).
no(13,carlos,[natureza,musica,sw,futebol,coimbra]).
```

I'm trying to get the users with X common tags with an user

I have this code but it returns false instead of a list

can anyone help me please?

```
uc(USER, X, L) :-
    findall(N, no(N,_,_), Ns),
    intersectioUserList(USER,Ns,X,L).
%

intersectioUserList(_, [], _, _).
intersectioUserList(USER, [H|T], X, L):-
    intersectioUserList(USER, T, X, L),
    intersectionUser(USER,H,X,L).
%

intersectionUser(USER,Y,X,L):-
    no(USER,_,L1),
    no(Y,_,L2),
    intersection(L1,L2,L3),
    list_length(L3,T),
    ((T >= X) -> append([Y],L,L)).
%


list_length([]     , 0 ).
    list_length([_|Xs] , L ) :- list_length(Xs,N) , L is N+1 .
%
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: Forget about list_length/2, use length/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need to compute the intersection of the two lists, just see if the desired tag appears in both of them (using [member/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2)).

```
uc(Uid1, Tag, Users) :-
    no(Uid1, _, Tags1),
    member(Tag, Tags1),
    dif(Uid1, Uid2),
    findall(Uid2, (no(Uid2, _, Tags2), member(Tag, Tags2)), Users).

no( 1, ana,    [natureza, pintura, musica, sw,      porto]).
no(11, antonio,[natureza, pintura, carros, futebol, lisboa]).
no(12, beatriz,[natureza, musica,  carros, porto,   moda]).
no(13, carlos, [natureza, musica,  sw,     futebol, coimbra]).
```

Examples:

```
?- uc(1, natureza, Users).
Users = [11, 12, 13] ;
false.

?- uc(User, Tag, Users).
User = 1,
Tag = natureza,
Users = [11, 12, 13] ;

User = 1,
Tag = pintura,
Users = [11] ;

User = 1,
Tag = musica,
Users = [12, 13] ;

User = 1,
Tag = sw,
Users = [13] 
...
true
```

**EDIT**

To obtain a list *Users* of users with at least *MinNumberOfTags* tags in common with a given user *Uid1* you will need [intersection/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3):

```
% uc(+Uid1, +MinNumberOfTags, -Users)

uc(Uid1, MinNumberOfTags, Users) :-
    no(Uid1, _, Tags1),
    dif(Uid1, Uid2),
    findall( Uid2,
             ( no(Uid2, _, Tags2),
               intersection(Tags1, Tags2, CommonTags),
               length(CommonTags, N),
               N >= MinNumberOfTags ),
             Users ).
```

Example:

```
?- uc(11, 1, Users).
Users = [1, 12, 13].

?- uc(1, 1, Users).
Users = [11, 12, 13].
```

**NOTE**

SWI-Prolog defines the predicate `intersection/3` as:

```
intersection([], _, []) :- !.
intersection([X|T], L, Intersect) :-
    memberchk(X, L),
    !,
    Intersect = [X|R],
    intersection(T, L, R).
intersection([_|T], L, R) :-
    intersection(T, L, R).
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i might have not explain my self correctly.
I need the predicate to give me a list with the users with X common Tags. for example.
uc(11, 1, L) -> this should return a list L with all user with at least 1 tag in common with user 11.
Is there any solution for this problem?
thank you so much

Comment: @EmanuelSalvadinho See section EDIT in my answer.

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. it helped me a lot to understand